# Book where two people travel to the past. One becomes a member of the rich/elite, while the other was poor

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

Maybe five years ago, I heard of a book that sounded really interesting.

I don't remember the specifics exactly, but from what I remember, two people travel to the past. Somehow they get separated, I believe, and one becomes a member of the rich/elite, while the other becomes poor.

I apologize if all of the details aren't correct, but I have been trying to find what this book is for years.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you hear about this book? And are you confident that you'll be able to recognise the correct book if it's found, without actually having read it? It is possible after all that there's more than one book with a plot matching this rather brief description.

Comment: Thank you!  It was maybe 5 years ago? Was hoping that the plot line of 2 people going back in time, resulting in 2 opposing social classes, wouldn’t be too brief of a description. I actually talked to my local librarian who knew of the book, but could not locate the title. Been looking ever since.

Comment: Harry Harrisons 'A rebel in time' would fit; was published a lot longer ago but still available. I suspect there will be other examples and it might not be easy to narrow it down to a unique title.

Comment: This one is from 1976. One character becomes a right hand to the noble in medieval society, the other becomes a slave to a different noble. No time travel, but space travel to medieval technology planet https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheWitling

Comment: Ok, so I am going to definitely check these out! Thank you both for the replies! I’m so glad I found this site! Great to interact with everyone!